# Why isn't my bound value updating with each keystroke?

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor

I have two html components - an `<input type="text"/>` and a `<label/>`. The goal is to have the value of the label update with each keystroke of the textbox.

The text input is setup like this:

```
<input type="text" @bind="@SelectedField.Name"/>
```

The behavior that I'm seeing is the value of the `text-input` isn't propagating to `SelectedField.Name` with each keystroke. I setup an `@onKeyUp` event to check this. Entering values into the `text-input` isn't updating the value of `SelectedField.Name` until after the `text-input` is destroyed.

This implementation is in .NET 7.

How I tested this:

```
<input type="text" @bind="@SelectedField.Name" @onkeyup="() => CheckData()"/>

@code {
    public void CheckData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SelectedField.Name);
    }
}
```

1. The initial value of `SelectedField.Name` is `String.Empty`
2. Expected behavior is that on every key-press, the value of the `text-input` is printed to the console.
3. Actual behavior is that on every key-press, an empty string is printed to the console.

Is this a bug? Am I using the `@bind` functionality incorrectly? I'm coming from Angular so maybe I'm looking at this with the wrong pattern.

Comment: shouldn't it be `@bind-value="..."`?

Comment: @Jonathan `@bind` is a shortcut override of `@bind-value` with the event set to `onchange`. `@bind="someProperty"` is equivalent to `@bind-value="someProperty" @bind-value:event="onchange"`.

Comment: Well then I just learned something new i think

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to call `StateHasChanged`.

Here's a simple demo of a field being updating on each keystroke.

```cs
@page "/" 

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>


<input class="form-control mb-3" @bind=this.SelectedField.Name @bind:event="oninput" />
<label>@this.SelectedField.Name</label>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @this.SelectedField.Name
    </div>


@code {
    private Model SelectedField = new();

    public class Model
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Or are you trying to do something like this in a component, and wanting to drive updates to display fields in the parent?

```cs
<input class="form-control mb-3" @bind=this.SelectedField.Name @bind:event="oninput" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public Model SelectedField { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Comment: If I'm following, I think `SelectedItem` is being passed as a parameter to a child component and the OP wants the update from the child component to bubble up to the parent. I could be all wrong, though, because OP claims that adding a call to `StateHasChanged()` resolves the issue which I don't think would be true for the situation I describe. In short, I'm confused and don't think we have all the required info to provide a good answer.

Comment: You're certainly right about missing information: but then, when do we every get told the full story!!!  I read "html components" to be just elements on the page, there's no evidence of a proper component in the code we've been shown.  Let's wait and see.  Sometimes educated guesses are close, sometimes, wrong universe.  I've added a `label` into my answer for good measure.